# How to sync scroll of two Horizontal recycler views

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, synchronization, horizontal-scrolling

I have two recycler views with different view with the Horizontal orientation, I want to sync scroll of both of them, like if i scroll upper recycler, bottom recycler should also change its position as well visa versa. Please help 
Here is my code

```
private var draggingView = -1
 val scrollListner: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener =
            object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                    if (draggingView == 1 && recyclerView == imageCategory) {
                        circularRecycler.scrollBy(dx, dy)
                    } else if (draggingView == 2 && recyclerView == circularRecycler) {
                        imageCategory.scrollBy(dx, dy)
                    }
                }

                override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                    if (imageCategory == recyclerView && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                        draggingView = 1;
                    } else if (circularRecycler == recyclerView && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                        draggingView = 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        imageCategory.addOnScrollListener(scrollListner)
        circularRecycler.addOnScrollListener(scrollListner)
```